# How fetch the request details from the Request body ifrom RequestHandleMiddleware

Tags: scala, zio-http, zio-streams

I am trying the fetch the `MappingInputRequest` details from the `RequestHandlerMiddleware`.

Tried with `val req= request.body.asStream` which converts into `ZStream[Any,thowable,Byte]`.

On top of that I tried with `runCollect` and `flatmap`.

Comment: What do you want to get and in which format/type? What are the "request details" you're looking for?